# "Ora sono in regola": uso dell'espressione "essere in regola"

Tags: word-usage

Care e cari, sto traducendo un romanzo italiano dove una migrante dice:

> Ora sono in regola.

So che vuol dire che i suoi documenti sono in regola, che ha dei documenti. Però,  quel che mi interessa è: questa frase esatta è marcata?, è un po' slang?, o no? (linguaggio perfetto o linguaggio burocratico?)

Italiani, forza a tutti dal cuore, un saluto dalla Slovenia.

Comment: Benvenuta/o su Italia.SE!

Comment: Cara Alenka, trovo vani i saluti di forma, ma le parole nel tuo post sono di grande umanità e per questo ti ringrazio. Mi piace anche la domanda che hai posto, e quindi grazie di nuovo.

Answer (score 1):

L'espressione "Essere in regola" è a mio avviso colloquiale e non burocratica; un'espressione analoga, leggermente più formale è

> avere i documenti in regola

Nel caso "burocratico" l'espressione corretta dovrebbe essere secondo me

> avere documenti validi

oppure

> essere in possesso di documenti validi

Comment: Perché sarebbe "gergale"?

Comment: @Charo hai ragione, probabilmente 'gergale' è eccessivo, modifico la mia risposta

Comment: E davvero credi che sia "colloquiale", cioè, caratteristico delle conversazioni piuttosto informali?

Comment: Ho cercato esempi di "ero in regola" su Google Books (sono più facili da trovare di quelli di "(io) sono in regola") e quelli che ho trovato non mi sembrano particolarmente colloquiali.

Comment: @charo penso proprio di sì (sarà solo una mia opinione); se guardo questa pagina per esempio https://www.interno.gov.it/it/temi/immigrazione-e-asilo/modalita-dingresso parlano di visti "validi" non di visti "in regola".

Comment: Sì, @RiccardoDeContardi, ma "non burocratico" non è sinonimo di "colloquiale".

Answer (score 1):

Trovo che “essere in regola” sia normale italiano standard, non burocratico, ma neppure particolarmente colloquiale o gergale.

Si trova la locuzione “in regola” per esempio nella voce “[regola](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/regola)” del Treccani (al punto 1.d), senza particolari marche d'uso. Idem per il dizionario di De Mauro che registra proprio la locuzione “[in regola](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/in-regola)”.